# C#: How to use Service References in Visual Studio 2015 (Move from Linqpad)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, linqpad

I would like to migrate a C# Program to Visual Studio. I'm fairly new working with C#, however I could have learned some stuff in Linqpad.
In Linqpad I imported my dll as an additional Reference and could use it. The dll was generated with:

```
"wsdl http://localhost/WebService.asmx"
```

and

```
"csc /t:library WebService.cs"
```

Linqpad Code which worked was like:

```
WebService ws = new WebService();
void Main()
{
    try
    {
        var connect = ws.Logon("localhost", Port, "", "username", "password);
        var morefiles = false;
    // do other stuff....

    do
    {
        var results = ws.search(connect, "Culture", "Culture", searchCondition, morefiles);
    } while (morefiles == true);
    }
    catch (Exception x)
    {
    Console.WriteLine(x.Message);
    Console.WriteLine(x.StackTrace);
    }
    finally {
    Console.WriteLine("Search done");
    }
}
```

Now, I would like to use it in Visual Studio. In VS I imported it as a Service References with the given URL, and it showed me the necessary stuff.
Now when I try to use it in my code I get an error message which tells me:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Testproject.WebService;

namespace Testproject
{

    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WebService ws = new WebService();
            Console.WriteLine("Test");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

The error message is in the line:

```
WebService ws = new WebService();
```

It shows me this error message:

> WebService is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'type'

I also found out, that "Logon" which I used in Line 6 in Linqpad is in:

> WebService.WebServiceSoap

However, if I change the line in:

```
WebService.WebServiceSoap ws = new WebService.WebServiceSoap();
```

I also get an error message:

> Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface

I tried different combinations also, but I don't exactly no, what can be wrong. Can you help me?

Comment: LinqPad generated one set of classes for the specified WSDL, while Visual Studio generated a different one. If you check any WCF tutorial, you'll see that the generated proxy class is typically called `SomeServiceNameClient`. In your case, it would be `WebServiceClient`. You are trying to use the namespaces and interfaces used by the proxy instead of the proxy itself

Comment: PS `asmx` services are obsolete. They don't support the WS-* interoperability standards introduced since 2008.